# Wrong retrieved date format from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am saving the date in the database like `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` and the format looks like `yyyy-MM-dd` in the database.

The problem is when I retrieve that date using a select query it gets a date like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt`.

My question is how to get the date from database in its format `yyyy-MM-dd`?

For example:

- date in my database table : 2018-12-03
- date retrieved: 2018-12-03 12:00:00 AM

I want the date to be retrieved like : 2018-12-03

Any suggestions?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: you can convert the date value to a string and format it the way you desire.  i cannot tell what your code looks like so cannot assist further at this stage

Comment: What type are you trying to get from the database? If it is `DateTime` and not string - it is just initialized with a default values, and you cannot do anything with it. So it will be better if you will show us how are you trying to use this retrieved data and where is the real problem?

Comment: Clarifying question: your original question is tagged as C#, but it seems like you're asking a SQL Server question based on the title... just want to confirm what you need?  Do you need to convert in C# or via a SQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that the column in your table is still defined as a full datetime so no matter how you insert or update it, it's going to add the extra info.  All you need to do is use the convert function on select:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

```
SELECT convert([columnName],varchar(10),111) FROM [tablename]
```

Comment: thanks .. the problem is from the query not from the code in c#

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dateVariable, "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    ).ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your result into string/exact date format you want, using
  **CONVERT(desired-type, your data, format)**. Take a look on my following code snippets:

```
 declare @date as datetime
 declare @string varchar(30)
 declare @tempDate date

 set @date = '2012-02-03 12:00:03 AM'
 --convert into string format
 set @string = CONVERT(varchar, @date, 1)
 --convert into Date format, you want
 set @tempDate = CONVERT(date, @date,1)

 select @string as time
 select @tempDate as another
```